# How to Set Checked and Enabled Property On CheckBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to make a checkBox that is both

```
Checked = true
```

and

```
Enabled = false
```

How can I do this?

I wrote this code, but it removes `Checked` from the checkBox

```
chkDecreaseAbsenceFromExtraWork.Enabled = !SecurityManager.HasAccess(Session, AccessCode.EditDecreaseAbsenceFromExtraWorkIsImpossible);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a CheckBox Control

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
```

You set it to checked and disabled

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        CheckBox1.Enabled = false;
        CheckBox1.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Eugene Podskal is right in that the values are not submitted. However ViewState will still set the CheckBox to checked after a PostBack.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "CheckBox is " + CheckBox1.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems to be by design feature of the HTML itself - [values of disabled inputs will not be submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted)

You can try

1. Either to use a [hidden fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield?view=netframework-4.7.2) and synchronize its checkbox's value with it in the form - that is if you really need to have a disabled input.
2. Or you can make that [checkbox readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134057/how-to-make-checkbox-readonly-in-web-application)